# difference with "take" in clojure and clojurescript?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

i faced a super weird issue today

```
(let [t :cognitive
      tab (name t)
      tab-name (string/join "" (take 3 (string/split tab #"")))]
  (println "@@@" t tab tab-name))
```

returns

```
@@@ :cognitive cognitive cog
```

in clojure, but

```
@@@ :cognitive cognitive co
```

in clojurescript (rendered using reagent). notice the missing `g` in the cljs version

i have tried `doall` before-and-after the `(take 3 ...` expression, but to no avail

BTW, i'm using

```
[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]
[org.clojure/clojurescript "1.7.170"]
```

for my cljs project, and

```
[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
```

for the clj project

Comment: I'm guessing there's some other reason you're using `string/split` on the string, but just thought I'd mention that strings are coerced to sequences.  So you could just use `(take 3 tab)` in your example.

Comment: hey @NathanDavis, i didn't think of that. thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cljs:

```
(string/split (name :cognitive) #"")
```

gives you:

```
["" "c" "o" "g" "n" "i" "t" "i" "v" "e"]
```

So your `(take 3 ...` is taking `""`, `"c"`, and `"o"`.

As to why--it is possible that the underlying `String.split` java method called by clojure and clojurescript is behaving differently between versions. [edited]

Comment: It's not Clojure 1.7 that's behaving that way, it's ClojureScript that is.  I wonder if this is a difference in regex engines leaking through the abstraction?  `(string/split "foo" "")` yields the right results in ClojureScript, but fails because it's not a regex pattern in Clojure.

Comment: @jszakmeister In clojure, `(string/split "foo" #"")` is definitely a valid pattern.  Regarding the rest of what you wrote, I used a phone app version of the repl to test that and it was 1.7.0-alpha5 so I made the mistake of thinking it was clojure.  I think you may be right that it's a regex code difference. Often a regex function will return a match in the first position of the returned vector, so that's probably what's happening.

Comment: Correct, `(string/split "foo" #"")` has a valid regex pattern, but I wrote `(string/split "foo" "")` (no hash in front of the empty string).  That splits the string correctly in ClojureScript but fails in Clojure.